# Flutter detect triple tap

Tags: flutter

I would like to be able to detect a triple tap (or even more) in a Flutter widget, although GestureDetector only has detection for double-tap built in.

What is the easiest way for me to detect a triple tap on a widget?

(I want continually clicking on a part of the screen to unlock some developer options)

Answer (score 13):

Was a bit lazy with this one, in reality it's not that hard

```
// init
int lastTap = DateTime.now().millisecondsSinceEpoch;
int consecutiveTaps = 0;

GestureDetector(
        onTap: () {
          int now = DateTime.now().millisecondsSinceEpoch;
          if (now - lastTap < 1000) {
            print("Consecutive tap");
            consecutiveTaps ++;
            print("taps = " + consecutiveTaps.toString());
            if (consecutiveTaps > 4){
              // Do something
            }
          } else {
            consecutiveTaps = 0;
          }
          lastTap = now;
        },
        child: ...
)
```

Comment: You might want to use 300 milliseconds, that's what the Flutter framework uses for the double tap timeout: https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/gestures/kDoubleTapTimeout-constant.html

Answer (score 6):

I tried the method mentioned here, but it didn't work for me. GestureDetector onTap is called only once,
regardless of the number of taps. Probably something has changed in flutter (I'm on the beta channel).
However, I dug into the source code of flutter and come to the solution (https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/gestures/SerialTapGestureRecognizer-class.html):

```dart
import "package:flutter/gestures.dart";
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

RawGestureDetector(
  gestures: {
    SerialTapGestureRecognizer:
        GestureRecognizerFactoryWithHandlers<SerialTapGestureRecognizer>(
            SerialTapGestureRecognizer.new,
            (SerialTapGestureRecognizer instance) {
      instance.onSerialTapDown = (SerialTapDownDetails details) {
         if (details.count == 3) print('Consecutive tap 3');
      };
    })
  },

  //  child: // your widget,
);
```

Answer (score 2):

I took a little different approach. Instead of having to compare timestamps, I set a Timer, which will reset the tapped state. But each time there is a tap, the old timer is canceled.

```dart
Timer? devPageClickTimer;
num devPageTapped = 0;
final devPageTapGoal = 5;

GestureDetector(
  onTap: () {
    devPageTapped++;
    if (devPageTapped >= devPageTapGoal) {
      router.push(const DeveloperRoute());
    }

    if (devPageClickTimer != null) {
      devPageClickTimer!.cancel();
    }

    devPageClickTimer = Timer(const Duration(milliseconds: 200), () => devPageTapped = 0);
},
```

Answer (score 2):

I have tried this method with reduced timeout and with both double and triple tap

```
int lastTap = DateTime.now().millisecondsSinceEpoch;
int consecutiveTaps = 1;
GestureDetector(
      onTap: () {
        int now = DateTime.now().millisecondsSinceEpoch;
        if (consecutiveTaps == 1) {
          print("taps = " + consecutiveTaps.toString());
          lastTap = now;
        }
        if (now - lastTap < 300) {
          print("Consecutive tap");
          consecutiveTaps++;
          print("taps = " + consecutiveTaps.toString());
          if (consecutiveTaps == 3) {
            print("Consecutive tap 3");
          } else if (consecutiveTaps == 2) {
             print("Consecutive tap 2");
          }
        } else {
          consecutiveTaps = 1;
        }
        lastTap = now;
      },
      child: \\child);
```

Answer (score 2):

***Relevant solution***.
Here is flexible reusable multiple tap widget based on Listener widget that reports raw pointer events:

```
class AppMultipleTap extends StatefulWidget {
  final Widget child;
  final VoidCallback onMultipleTap;
  final int taps;
  final Duration duration;

  const AppMultipleTap({
    super.key,
    required this.child,
    required this.onMultipleTap,
/// feel free to override these values
    this.taps = 3,
    this.duration = const Duration(milliseconds: 600),
  });

  @override
  State<AppMultipleTap> createState() => _AppMultipleTapState();
}

class _AppMultipleTapState extends State<AppMultipleTap> {
/// in _count we store current number of taps
  int _count = 0;
  Timer? _timer;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Listener(
      onPointerDown: (_) {
        if (_timer == null) _startTimer();
        _count++;
      },
      child: widget.child,
    );
  }

  void _startTimer() {
    _timer = Timer(widget.duration, () {
/// you can change this condition to ==, if you need 100% match
      if (_count >= widget.taps) {
        widget.onMultipleTap.call();
      }
      _timer = null;
      _count = 0;
    });
  }
}
```

Then you can use it like that:

```
 @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return AppMultipleTap(
      onMultipleTap: /// Do some action
```

Answer (score 1):

I like this simple approach, without so many nested if blocks.

```
// Variables in the state class
var startTap = timeNow;
var consecutiveTaps = 0;
static const int serialTaps = 4;
static const int tapDurationInMs = 1000;
static int get timeNow => DateTime.now().millisecondsSinceEpoch;

// Build method
GestureDetector(
  onTap: () {
    final now = timeNow;
    final userExceededTapDuration = now - startTap > tapDurationInMs;

    if (userExceededTapDuration) {
      consecutiveTaps = 0;
      startTap = now;
    }

    consecutiveTaps++;

    if (consecutiveTaps == serialTaps) {
      // widget.onTap();
    }
  },
);
```