# How to create a triple tap gesture in flutter?

Tags: flutter, gesturedetector

I would like to add a onTripleTap gesture to a Flutter Button or the GestureDetector, do anyone knows how to create that gesture besides adding a counterTap?

this is what I've tried:

```
 int tapCounter = 0; 
   bool oneOption = false;

_tripleTapped() {
        setState(() {
          if (tapCounter == 3) {
            oneOption = true;
            print('The option was gave');
          }
          if (tapCounter >= 4) {
            oneOption = false;
            tapCounter = 0;
          }
          print('Option status: $oneOption');
        });
      }
```

The thing is that with the counter, the taps have to be very slow because if I tap the button 3 times fast it will trigger the onDoubleTap option and then increase the tabCounter with 1.

Comment: Have you checked this one : https://stackoverflow.com/q/59625936/7666442

Comment: Yes, I have read that post. If you see my example is somewhat similar to that one you suggest. The difference is that I set the tapCounter++ in the onTap option in the button, not in the _tripleTapped like the one in the other example. 

As I said, this doesn't give me the fluency I'm looking for. I want that the user hit 3 taps like the 2 taps options, not tap 1, tap, 2, tap 3... that takes too long.